# win32 byte array into LISTBOX

Tags: c++, winapi

i have BYTE[6] = {54, 61, 6c, 6f}.
How to add this Byte Array as LISTBOX item exactly to show 54616c6f?
LISTBOX always convert this hexa values to ASCII characters, also with recasting Byte array.

Comment: The behavior of the `ListBox` is correct. You have to convert the values to the hexadecimal string representation of your choice by yourself before adding them to the `ListBox`.

Comment: Use a [List-View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview) instead, add whatever data you need to your items, and use the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` to have the system call you back when it needs to produce a display string for your items.

Comment: @IInspectable that is an optimization at best, but doesn't do anything to address the OP's actual question about how to display the bytes as hex strings. Whether a ListBox or ListView is used, the same issue remains

Comment: @rem: This is a comment not an answer. Choosing a list-view isn't just an optimization. It's an architectural decision, one you want to take when you need to construct a custom display string. I didn't address the OP's question simply because I don't even know what it is. I was under the impression, that converting a sequence of bytes to some number representation were a solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting an array of bytes to a hex string is very easy. You can use a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::basic_string<TCHAR> toHex(BYTE bytes[], int count)
{
    std::basic_ostringstream<TCHAR> oss;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        oss << std::hex << std::noshowbase << (WORD)bytes[i];
    }
    return oss.str();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/PmvQIF)

If your [ListBox control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-boxes) has the [`LBS_HASSTRINGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-box-styles) style, you can add a string to it using the [`LB_ADDSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-addstring) message, eg:

```cpp
BYTE bytes[6] = {0x54, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6f};
std::basic_string<TCHAR> hexStr = toHex(bytes, 4);
SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hexStr.c_str()));
```

If you are using the Win32 ANSI/Unicode-based APIs directly, instead of using the `TCHAR`-based APIs, then simply replace `std::basic_ostringstream<TCHAR>` with `std::ostringstream` or `std::wostringstream`, and `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` with `std::string` or `std::wstring`, as needed.

Comment: Finally it works, Streams very helped me. Thank You.